# What causes a distortion in the output characteristic at low Vds?

Tags: mosfet, dc, powermosfet

Attached are the output characteristics of two different LDMOS transistors, extracted from TCAD simulation, where V<sub>gs</sub> = 3.3V.

The output conductance clarifies the distortion more.

What are the causes of this behavior? Any recommended literature for a detailed explanation?

[image]

Comment: Miller effect, gate charge, and a sweep rate in simulation that is too fast to allow these effects to be ignored. Re-run the sim at a lower sweep rate. Any MOSFET datasheet should show you the relevant parameters and any guide to MOSFET switching should explain the relevance.

Comment: You need to explain what the axes on the graphs are and what the different colour lines represent.